# How do I send soap request in nodejs without having wsdl

Tags: node.js, soap, request

How do I send soap request in nodejs without having wsdl?
All nodejs soap libs are working with wsdl url.
Is there and easier way then to build the XML and the request myself?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use Fiddler to catch soap payload(XML) for the request. use that with httpclient.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use any http client like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

you still need the wsdl though because otherwise, how do you know what's the format required for request?

You can use sth like [soap-convert](https://github.com/buianhthang/soap-converter) to convert wsdl to postman collection or openapi format.

Comment: For example, image the web services are well documented but the WSDL it is providing is ill-formed. If you only need to access a few endpoints, it seems reasonable to just write this yourself. Especially if you do not have control of said web services.